# Arcpy get values in the 2nd field of every table in a geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, cursor, fields-attributes, loop, search

I have a geodatabase in Oracle with around 50 tables. I want to get the values in the 2nd field of every table in my geodatabase.  I will be using the values in the 2nd field as an input for a geoprocessing tool. The 2nd field name is different in every table but the values are what I need for the tool. This is the code i'm working with so far:

```
import arcpy
aWS = r"C:\Users\dav\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcCatalog\Connection to OracleGDB.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = aWS

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

luList = arcpy.ListTables("*LK")
for lu in luList:
    print lu

    Desc = "DESCRIPTION"

    cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(lu)
    for row in cursor:
        print(row.getValue(Desc))


       #Get the values in the 2nd field of lu and put it in the "2ndField" input

       #Run Table to Domain function
       arcpy.TableToDomain_management(lu, 2ndField, Desc, "NewGeo.gdb", 2ndFieldName, "DESCRIPTION")
```

Comment: Have a look at arcpy.listfields.  Also you should be using arcpy.da.searchcursor instead.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at that:  'fields = arcpy.ListFields(lu) for field in fields: print field.name' but I'm not sure how to get the 2nd field

Comment: Once you've done that, to get the second element of the list called fields, just fields[1].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import arcpy
aWS = r"C:\Users\dav\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcCatalog\Connection to OracleGDB.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = aWS

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

luList = arcpy.ListTables("*LK")
for lu in luList:
    print lu

    #Get the name of the second field in the current table
    fieldsInTable = arcpy.ListFields(lu)
    secondFieldName = fieldsInTable[1].name
    print "Second field in " + lu + " is named: " + secondFieldName

    Desc = "DESCRIPTION"

    cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(lu)
    for row in cursor:
        print(row.getValue(Desc))


       #Get the values in the 2nd field of lu and put it in the "2ndField" input
       secondFieldValue = str(row.getValue(secondFieldName)

       #Let's map my variables to your tool's variables
       #You can change this if you need to - I'm making assumptions here
       2ndFieldName = secondFieldName
       2ndField = secondFieldValue

       #Run Table to Domain function
       arcpy.TableToDomain_management(lu, 2ndField, Desc, "NewGeo.gdb", 2ndFieldName, "DESCRIPTION")
```

Comment: This may answer your question on how to get the second field name, but the code to load the domain is incorrect. I guess that would be a different question though.

Comment: This worked and I was able to get the second field name, but @RHB is correct; I am unable to populate domains from the Oracle database. Any clue on how to do that? I suppose I'll ask another question formally